# Android, multiples alarms with time picker

Tags: android, alarmmanager, timepicker, android-alarms, android-timepicker

I was trying to use the time picker to 5 alarms with meals of the day, the truth investigate much about it and what I found is a little confusing.
I did it in a way that is not very "efficient" but having no experience in this matter I could not think otherwise.
Now the problem is that if I make the 5 alarms but when I think a min apart sometimes one or two of them does not work.
example:
I have a RelativeLayout where they are showing alarms in a TextView so:
alarm 1
alarm 2
alarm 3
alarm 4
alarm 5

Alarm 2 sometimes does not work or the 2 and 4. This when placed with a minute apart.

The truth is that the code is not very good but still should create 5 and functioning but that's so.

I hope someone can's take me a hand.

Thank You

This is the code and classes that did

```
public class Recordatorios2 extends Activity {

Button buttonstartSetDialog;
TextView desayuno,merienda1,almuerzo,merienda2,cena;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
private Spinner alarma;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recordatorios2);
    llenarSpinnerAlarmas();

    desayuno = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Desayuno);
    merienda1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Merienda1);
    almuerzo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Almuerzo);
    merienda2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Merienda2);
    cena = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cena);

    alarma = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAlarma);
    buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //  desayuno.setText("");
            openTimePickerDialog(false);
        }
    });
     }


 public void llenarSpinnerAlarmas(){

    alarma = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAlarma);
    //Creamos el adaptador
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Alarmas,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    //Añadimos el layout para el menú
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //Le indicamos al spinner el adaptador a usar
    alarma.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
            Recordatorios2.this,
            onTimeSetListener,
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            is24r);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Elija la alarma");

    timePickerDialog.show();
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
        = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

       calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


        if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        setAlarm(calSet);
    }};

private void setAlarm( Calendar targetCal) {

    if(alarma.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Desayuno")){

        RelativeLayout recordatorios = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.recordatoriosLayout);
        desayuno.setText("Desayuno: " + targetCal.getTime());
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),1 , intent1, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);

    }else if(alarma.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Primera Merienda")){
        RelativeLayout recordatorios = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.recordatoriosLayout);
        merienda1.setText("Primer Merienda: " + targetCal.getTime());
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),2 , intent2,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);

    }else if(alarma.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Almuerzo")){
        RelativeLayout recordatorios = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.recordatoriosLayout);
        almuerzo.setText( "Almuerzo: " + targetCal.getTime());
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),3 , intent3, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager3.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent3);

    }else if(alarma.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Segunda Merienda")){
        RelativeLayout recordatorios = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.recordatoriosLayout);
        merienda2.setText( "Segunda Merienda: " + targetCal.getTime());
        Intent intent4 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),4 , intent4,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager4 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager4.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent4);

    } else if(alarma.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Cena")){
        RelativeLayout recordatorios = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.recordatoriosLayout);
        cena.setText("Cena: " + targetCal.getTime());
        Intent intent5 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent5 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),5 , intent5, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager5 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager5.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent5);


}
}



}
```

Now in this class I would like to specify when each alarm to send a different message but nose obtaining an id or identifier of each intent of each alarm, how could I do?

I will step i tried and tried to make i.getId or something similar but apparently can not.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent i) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "alarma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: implement `setAlarm()` method in `AlarmReceiver` class

Comment: but as I do that ????, what happens is that this method is typical of the kind of things where I think he will not be able to do the same in kind as alarreceiver also could use so you can identify the intent to so customize each message you must show ???
Also try to implement a method to stop the alarm but did not know that id like this at that time or that intent and not as accessible.

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://www.steventrigg.com/alarm-manager-create-an-alarm-clock-in-android-tutorial-part-6/

Comment: Man, try to follow this tutorial but it made me very complicated and also had things that gave me error.
I need to know is that some of the alarms I program not sound or accumulate other alarms me, because sometimes I sound up to 3 at a time.
Sorry for this trouble but I'm new to all I am and the beginning is difficult

Comment: already solved it, what I did was use this to generate different id for each intent.
  final int _id = ((int) System.currentTimeMillis () / 1000);
         Random generator = new Random ();
         int id_nuevo = (_id + generator.nextInt ());